# How to export member type after an advanced search

Tags: search, export

I am doing an advanced search in our database.

Members Current - Primary
and a proximity search for these members to be within 100kms of a postal code.

my problem:
when I go to export my results I would like it to show the MEMBER type as well as some basic contact details.
I do not know how to add this field and it isn't in any of the fields available for selection "Member Type"

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange Michael ^^

In the upper left corner of the Advanced search you will find a dropdown field called "Display Results As". If you select memberships the search will yield a list of memberships instead of contacts.

You should then be able to select "Export Members" from the action menu and include all membership details including the type.